# Tableau: COUNTD IF multiple dimensions are met

Tags: string, tableau-api

I would like to make a bar graph with each bar representing the number of companies that meet different sets of criteria.

For the first bar, I want to display the number of companies that have signed Contract 1 and are environmental companies.

Here's what I've tried with no success:
'COUNTD(IF [CHANNEL_TYPE] = "Environment" AND [Contract_1] = "signed" THEN [Company] END)'

Comment: You should separate the filter from the result to test whether your filter logic works. What problem do you observe?

Comment: What do you get as a result ?
Have you got the correct case for Environment and signed ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.